# What to do when your OpenID provider shuts down?

Tags: openid

I have been using http://chi.mp as an OpenID provider for a year or two without issues but in the last couple of months the site seems to be breaking down with error 500s, slow to no response etc.  Their Twitter account reveals that others have had similar issues for months and hints that things are generally not well behind the scenes.

What to do when your OpenID identity provider is going into limbo?

Is there a way to migrate to another OpenID server or is my only option to start fresh with a new provider (and new identity)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Stack Exchange, it's relatively easy to add a new Open ID provider to your account. (It's right next to the "edit" link on your profile.) Then you can authorize with either.

As far as other sites that use Open ID...that depends on the site.

<del>For what it's worth I've been using MyOpenID.com for a couple years and it has been very stable.</del>

Unfortunately, MyOpenID.com shut down earlier this year. Since I use Google extensively I've moved to Google's Open ID solution. I don't see them disappearing any time soon.

Comment: Agree - just today I added my gmail OpenID to Stack Exchange and it works flawlessly - a 5 second solution.  As for the other sites that don't support such linking, I may leave those identities to sacrifice.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Convert to a paid domain and move the domain. Once you own it and control it, turn that domain into your own OpenID provider.

[Purchase the Chi.mp Domain](https://secure.mp/s/premier.mp/purchase)

[Jeff Atwood's "Using Your Own URL as Your OpenID"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/using-your-own-url-as-your-openid/)

Comment: I would like to add that I purchased mine from get.mp and moved it to the free Google Apps edition where i enabled emailed for it then under Google App Engine I host it for free. The site has a single page with the 2 header tags described in Jeff's comments.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  It is definitely a valid option but too much work and ongoing maintenance for me currently (renewals, spam, ownership).  Although I won't rule this out, it's not my first option.

Comment: i understand - the .mp domain i had was too good to let go of.